# como hago una insercion multiple no dejando registros en blanco

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo un problema recibo variables mediante chatbot asi:

sabor1:  5, cantidad1: 3, codigo1: 1, precio1: 6.5

sabor2:  2, cantidad2: 6, codigo2: 2, precio2: 5

a veces solo recibo 1 dato o a veces mas de 2 entonces mi insert es asi

```
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO detallepedido(idpedido,idproducto,cantidad, precio, 
         subtotal)
         VALUES ('$sabor1','$codigo1', '$cantidad1', '$precio1','$subtotal1'),
         ('$sabor2','$codigo2', '$cantidad2', '$precio2','$subtotal2'),
         ('$sabor3','$codigo3', '$cantidad3', '$precio3','$subtotal3')";
         $mysqli->query($sql2);
```

y al momento de ingresar en mi tabla deja espacios en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria hacerlo con un while teniendo en cuenta que no se cuantos datos recibire

Comment: En que formato envia el chatbot la informacion ? es un string ? es un json? es un array ?

Comment: Mis datos los guardo como string  .

Comment: Puedes dividir cada fila y luego leer por filas para crear el INSERT. Pero para eso debes garantizar que cada fila termine igual, por ejemplo por `\n`. Para este tipo de cosas siempre ese mejor mandar algo estructurado como un JSON. También deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar *inyección SQL*.